# Is there a name for ring elements that multiply to zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily with identity). Is there a name for an element $a\in R$ for which $ab=0$ for all $b\in R$? Similarly, for an element $a\in R$ for which $ba=0$ for all $b\in R$?

Note, a unital ring has exactly one of each, just zero in both cases, as if $ab=0$ for all $b\in R$ then we can take $b=1$.

*Also, examples of non-unital rings that have non-trivial elements of this type would be appreciated.

Comment: Those are the elements which are left (resp. right) annihilators of the entire ring. If you are in a need of a single word, "left (right) annihilating element" should be fine, though not a term I've ever encountered in literature.

Comment: I suppose that is the term for the same idea applied to a ring's modules, so it seems suitable considering the ring to be a left/right module over itself :).

Comment: I guess the term is rarely used because there aren't too many very prominent examples, so any interesting examples would be great.

Comment: "Zero divisors"

Comment: @user247327, no, a zero divisor maps at least one non-zero element to zero, these elements map all to zero.